Help with Animating a Leech-like Creature on a Parent Character’s Deforming Surface
I’m working on an animation where I need to animate a leech-like creature (a rigged child character) moving along the surface of another rigged and animated parent character. The parent characters is humanoid with armature setups.
Ideally, I want the leech creature to move along the parent’s deforming mesh (for example, as the parent’s body or hands shift or fold), so that it remains in the correct relative position to the parent’s movements. The creature should appear to stick to the surface and follow the deformations seamlessly.
I’ve tried creating a curve on the parent’s surface and having the creature follow it, but when the parent deforms, the curve becomes distorted, and the movement no longer works as intended.
Is there a way to parent or constrain the creature to the parent’s deforming mesh so that it stays in place and moves correctly with the parent’s changes? Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you so much for your time and help!

In my example I go in cylinder edit mode, select 3 appropriate vertices, press Shift S > Selection to cursor.
In obj Mode create an empty, shift select the cylinder, press Ctrl P > Vertex Triangle, so that the empty will always follow the deformations of the three selected vertices.
Now in the armature IK target bone has a copy transform constraint targeting the empty, IK B bone has an IK constraint targeting IK target bone, chain lenght 2.
When bones Top and Bottom deform the cylinder, IK B tail remains always attached to the surface.
You could either use a Hook modifier to snap a curve's control point to the empty.

